# WatchEffect is triggered twice when watching a reactive object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch

If I run this code:

```
const state = reactive({
    title: '',
})

watchEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.title)
})
```

`watchEffect` is triggered and the console is outputting an empty `string`:

```
""
```

If I want to assign a new value to `state.title`, `watchEffect` is triggered twice. Is this behaviour expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is that the actual code you are using? When I run it, I see the console.log() being printed initially with the empty value, and then only being printed one time each time `state.title` is assigned a new value.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I'm asking. Should it print the initial empty string?  Shouldn't a watcher function trigger only, when the value changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect), `watchEffect`

> Runs a function **immediately** [emphasis added] while reactively tracking its dependencies
> and re-runs it whenever the dependencies are changed.

So it is expected that it should run twice in this situation: once when it is first defined, and then again when the value changes.

Answer (score 2):

As @MykWillis pointed out and is clearly stated in the docs, `watchEffect` runs immediately and on subsequent changes, exactly as `watch` with `{ immediate: true }` would.

If you do not want the effect to run initially, don't use `watchEffect`, use `watch` instead:

```js
const { createApp, watchEffect, reactive, toRefs, watch } = Vue;

createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      title: 'test',
    });

    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('watchEffect', state.title)
    });

    watch(() => state.title, () => {
      console.log('watch', state.title)
    });

    watch(() => state.title, () => {
      console.log('watch.immediate', state.title)
    }, { immediate: true })
    
    return { ...toRefs(state) }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="title">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
watchEffect(callback, {
   flush: 'post'
})
```